# Connecting to HBase when just hbase.zookeeper.quorum is given

Tags: python, hbase, apache-zookeeper, happybase

When `hbase-site.xml` is given by

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>hbase.zookeeper.quorum</name>
        <value>a.example.com,b.example.com,c.example.com</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort</name>
        <value>2181</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

How can I connect to HBase with happybase?

I tried to connect to one of them as

```
import happybase
conn = happybase.Connection('a.example.com', port=2181)
conn.open()
conn.close()
```

This shows the following error:

```
...
thrift.transport.TTransport.TTransportException: Could not connect to a.example.com:2181
```

Comment: Happybase uses the hadoop thrift API to communicate with HBase

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, because there was no thrift server running. Fixed it by:

```
hbase thrift start -threadpool
```